# Can series converge even if the general term does not have limit?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series, analysis, divergent-series

Consider the following series
$$\sum_{n \geq 1} \sin \left(\frac{n^2+n+1}{n+1} \pi\right)$$

The general term of the series does not go to zero, in fact $$\nexists\lim_{n \to \infty} \sin \left(\frac{n^2+n+1}{n+1} \pi\right) $$

Nevertheless on textbook I find that 
$$\sum_{n \geq 1} \sin \left(\frac{n^2+n+1}{n+1} \pi\right) = \sum_{n \geq 1} (-1)^n \sin \left(\frac{\pi}{n+1} \right)$$
Which converges conditionally.

I understand how to get the last series and why it converges conditionally, but I always thought that a **necessary** condition for any convergence of a series is that the limit of the general term is zero.

Am I missing something?

Comment: Yes, you are missing that the limit of the general term is zero. You simply assert it doesn't converge.

Comment: The sum will fail to be cauchy.  On the other hand, integrals like $\int_0^\infty\sin(x^2)dx$ can converge.

Comment: @SimpleArt The series does converge.

Comment: @SimpleArt: the series converges and is therefore Cauchy.

Comment: @Dr.MV I mean if the $n$th term didn't approach $0$.  Sorry, should've been more clear on that.

Comment: If you type a \mathrm{sin} b you see $a \mathrm{sin} b$ (without proper spacing), but if you type a\sin b you see $a\sin b$ (with proper spacing), and if you type a\sin(b) you see $a\sin(b)$ and you see that the space after $\sin$ depends on the context. I changed \mathrm{sin} to \sin in the question. The reason you saw $\displaystyle\mathrm{lim}_{n\to\infty}$ rather than $\displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty}$ is that you used \mathrm{lim} instead of \lim, which was designed for the occasion. I changed that too. $\qquad$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Note that $$\frac{n^2+n+1}{n+1}=n+\frac{1}{n+1}$$

Therefore, we can write

$$\sin\left(\frac{n^2+n+1}{n+1}\,\pi\right)=\sin\left(n\pi +\frac{\pi}{n+1}\right)=(-1)^n\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{n+1}\right)$$

Certainly, we have $\lim_{n\to \infty}(-1)^n\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{n+1}\right)=0$ and hence $\lim_{n\to \infty}\sin\left(\frac{n^2+n+1}{n+1}\,\pi\right)=0$ also.

So, the general terms of the series do approach $0$.  And in fact, by Leibniz's test for alternating series, we assert that

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \sin\left(\frac{n^2+n+1}{n+1}\,\pi\right)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^n\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{n+1}\right)$$

converges.

Answer (score 0):

This is a roundabout demonstration of convergence, but the main point is the acceleration of convergence.

The sum converges pretty slowly, but we can accelerate the convergence
$$
\begin{align}
\sum_{n=1}^\infty(-1)^n\sin\left(\frac\pi{n+1}\right)
&=\sum_{n=1}^\infty(-1)^n\sum_{k=0}^\infty(-1)^k\frac{\pi^{2k+1}}{(2k+1)!(n+1)^{2k+1}}\\
&=\sum_{n=1}^\infty(-1)^n\frac\pi{n+1}+\sum_{k=1}^\infty(-1)^k\frac{\pi^{2k+1}}{(2k+1)!}\left(\tfrac{4^k-1}{4^k}\zeta(2k+1)-1\right)\\
&=\pi(\log(2)\color{#C00000}{-1})+\sum_{k=1}^\infty(-1)^k\frac{\pi^{2k+1}}{(2k+1)!}\left(\tfrac{4^k-1}{4^k}\zeta(2k+1)\color{#C00000}{-1}\right)\\[6pt]
&=-0.52202133938400117822
\end{align}
$$
Note that the sum of the terms in red is $-\sin(\pi)=0$, but the approximation 
$$
\tfrac{4^k-1}{4^k}\zeta(2k+1)-1\sim-\frac1{2^{2k+1}}
$$
shows that they accelerate the convergence.